# Identify the process and application and kill the process Windows

Tags: batch-file

I have to identify and kill a application process, but the problem is that in task manager I have other application or proccess with the same name "Agent.exe"
I want to automate this process to kill and start the proccess, and don`t affect other process/services in Windows with the same name.

The agent is runing in c:\program files(86)...

Thanks,
MT

Comment: Does this process that you want kill... You want it kille for the current user? Also are you having this problem in your code or the actual task manager you want to kill it?

Answer (score 0):

If required, manipulate the targeted process so that it "looks" different, such as adding a synthetic command line argument or execute them as a different users etc.? With such manipulation you might use a command line tool (such as TASKLIST) to list candidate processes, filter the list (such as with FINDSTR) and then kill it with its process ID (TASKKILL).

If TASKLIST does not output enough information then you might need WMIC as `wmic path win32_process get ...` in http://waynes-world-it.blogspot.de/2008/07/process-list-with-command-line.html.

Answer (score 0):

Start the agent.exe process with a `start` command and add a window title.  Then you can use taskkill and filter on the window title.

```
 start "window title here" "c:\folder\agent.exe"
```